# Selecting first emoji auto selects last word of previous line

Tags: html, css

double clicking on first emoji to select it automatically selects previous line last word. How to prevent this?

Both lines are wrapped in different p tags

[image]

Comment: A good place to start is [mcve]

Comment: I mean is there any generic css based solution?

Comment: What code/system is this?